# Use LINQ to compare List in C#

Tags: c#, linq, grasshopper

I am writing a C#-component in Rhino Grasshopper. I whant to determine if the List `constraints` contains Point3d objects that are in the List `nodes`. If so, the entry in the return list `b` corresponding to entry in `nodes` should be `true`, otherwise `false`. To decide if a object is the same, a comparison tolerance `tol` is used.

As an example, let `nodes = {A, B, C, D, E, F}` and `constraints = {a, f}` be lists of Point3d objects. Since the distance between `A` and `a`, and `F` and `f` is equal or less than `tol`:

```
A.DistanceTo(a) <= tol  // True
```

we will get `b = {true, false, false, false, true}` as a return.

I guess I can find `b` using LINQ in some way.

Answer (score 5):

Seem you need LINQ `Select`:

```
var result = nodes.Select(n => constraints.Any(c => n.DistanceTo(c) <= tol));
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter: No Tim, it should be in `Select`, since OP want to have boolean list as result

Comment: There is no `Select` operation avalible for List<Point3d>. Do you mean `Find`?

Comment: @sehlstrom: did you add the line `using System.Linq;` on top?

Comment: It is allready there, however the `Select` option do not come up as an alternative when typing `nodes.`. Ignoring this, I get errors complaing over the usage of '>', ')' and that it expects ';' three times for the suggested row.

Comment: @sehlstrom: well I don't get what the error you got, please could you change the question accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
var b = from node in nodes
        let bs = constraints.Any(t => node.DistanceTo(t) <= tol)
        select bs;
```

Comment: That was I meant, but I get errors using the line. See comment to Cuong Le's answer.